# Haunted house movie with a scary mirror scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I probably saw this movie in the late 80s or early 90s.  It may have been a children's movie, but since neither my parents nor school had the best track record in picking appropriate movies, it may have been an adults' movie with a PG rating.  I just remember that it terrified me.

It was a live action colour movie about a family moving into what turns out to be a haunted house.  Two scenes I remember vividly.  First is a large bloodstain which the new owners order a maid to clean up.  It's easily removed, causing scoffing from the new owners, but it soon reappears.  Second is the bit that scared me.  One of the new family, probably the mother, is sitting at a dressing table and looking in a mirror.  Suddenly her reflection changes to show her looking hideously old and decayed, but a few moments later it changed back.

It's possible this is an adaptation of The Canterville Ghost, but the only version of that I've seen since then was animated.

Comment: There have been [many adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Canterville_Ghost#Adaptations) of _The Canterville Ghost_, but the bit with the reappearing bloodstain has also been used in many other horror stories; I'm afraid that doesn't narrow it down much. Not to mention a mirror image that changes.

Comment: I'm now confident that it was The Canterville Ghost.  Now to figure out which version.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176083/a-novel-about-ghost-set-in-england (about the book on which the movie is based)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've identified this as the [1986 adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Canterville_Ghost_(1986_film)) of The Canterville Ghost, starring John Gielgud.

[The full movie is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yT-pb3gQqWs&t=2101s).  The mirror scare scene happens at 34:30 and the bloodstain scrubbing scene is at 31:45.

Another childhood nightmare exorcised.